# How to fix font issue in figure?

Tags: fonts

I generate a figure from drawio then I get this Warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/lmr/bx/n' instead on input line 84.

File: build/assets/figures/sequence.xml.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use build/assets/figures/sequence.xml.pdf>
```

The `sequence.xml` file is converted into pdf with

```
drawio -x -fpdf -t --crop $< -o $@
```

How this warning can be fixed?

**EDIT**

The `sequence.xml` diagram is available [here](https://viewer.diagrams.net/?highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=sequence.xml#R7VjbctowEP0aHpvxlZLHBJL0IZ3JlHbaPgpLYE1kyyOLW7%2B%2BKyzZFjIJEKdJO2UYxnskra1zdldrBuE429wJVKSfOSZsEHh4MwgngyDwoyAYqK%2BHtxVy6UcVsBAU60kNMKW%2FiAY9jS4pJqU1UXLOJC1sMOF5ThJpYUgIvranzTmz71qgBXGAaYKYi36nWKYVOoq9Bv9E6CI1d%2FY9PZIhM1kDZYowX7eg8GYQjgXnsrrKNmPCFHmGl2rd7YHR%2BsEEyeUxC7QQK8SWem%2BD8GrMqFpePaDcml3DsxbqcpmxezonjOZgXRdE0IxIImCEafihwa7XKZVkWqBELV1DPACWyoyB5cMlSCQRLBG1zRgqSjrb3dUDRJBkKUq6Il9IWUWCQvlSqjuNa4UVOKeMjTnjylnOd4%2FnEqI5WhEhyaYFaYLuCIdHF1uYokeDOK6W6Gitw3DdaF8rnLZ0Dw2IdLwtat%2BNJHChVelWKHQV2heG5PhKRTVYM8aTx68pzWHrAN9SZogGSyeSH9gSuBTpW0gkFkRDwwoi2MoMl7M2J0O9fUEYkiCgnYcdnGh3D5yq8DP879F%2FuUdqyZciIXpNO9T33ICjJ%2F1Uu3X87PSpN3iUZJEjWQnsf8vhV95kiDJXQaD1Hs2gTFrKIEYXoOQkgYW7ZFJBS6EOXemBjGKsfECSQG6gJmkKtY3dxuLrQTzpVNlE1n4i1HVT%2B7NKU1eCfPAu%2FHAYv0xsM4XP5yV5qQJxV1mbErEiS%2FG%2FrunRKPLesK4Nn69rLTrdeG7rw4VM%2BYLniLUVcimKT6aou2RYBLn8RD3Q8%2FEvpKc7gF6Hn9Eb8HNyhtWJYggaHUdQ0EeCXToMJSlJHrsPoBZX%2B2fMjEvJMxgo4YSUptHg4NdgdpdhtSJmim49RmBjVKYE1%2FNhVz%2FAUGeIsX9WtufVyGSjK2FlbdtWS7MdeFC3djujw%2BeUdqanbiY4FBMn9zPDZxz119CYGH3f2RaN7HIUDv9cOfL95xnqvU3viGuzv7fo00Nf5Wzz8bvVODXOo5H3tKMe49x9Hc7J%2Bh217P6hpPgHenbffdMFigoOr01nHVetdOMFyd2TB7cOpfocsg4h72LY6wlUhbzVbJ1zKL0wT6PQTqhov9s4NjPD%2BBlHPWam%2B06N%2BTpnHOED6flKxfb9FdYoOLuwxk87Ols%2BMJu%2FMKvpzR%2FB4c1v). The command I use is similar to `Export As/PDF` with `export selection`.

Comment: Change `lm` for a font which has bold small caps.

Comment: @Bernard, where should I change this?

Comment: In the preamble. All fonts that work with latex can be used via a dedicated package. Other possibility: with xelatex and `fontspec`, you can use (for text) any font installed on your computer.

Comment: @Bernard, sorry I am lost I don't understand how can I set the `lm` for this `pdf` figure.

Comment: It is the default font if you use `T1` font encoding.

Comment: you would perhaps get better answers if you wouldn't expect that people know what "drawio" is and how it uses latex to create pictures.